# How to read the files and directories inside the directory

Tags: php

Can any one please let me know how to read the directory and find what are the files and directories inside that directory.

I've tried with checking the directories by using the `is_dir()` function as follows

```
$main = "path to the directory";//Directory which is having some files and one directory
readDir($main);

function readDir($main) {
    $dirHandle = opendir($main);
    while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            if (is_dir($file)) {
                 //nothing is coming here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not checking the directories.

Thanks

Comment: Is $main = "path to the directory"; set to the directory in question???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way in PHP 5 is with [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) and [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveIteratorIterator):

```
$dir = '/path/to/dir';
$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $path) {
  if ($path->isDir()) {
     // ...
  }
}
```

You don't need to recurse by yourself as these fine iterators handle it by themselves.

For more information about these powerful iterators see the linked documentation articles.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use full path to subdirectory:

```
if(is_dir($main.'/'.$file)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)
Then parse the result and eliminate '.' and '..' and `is_file()`

Comment: be aware, you should put the correct path (relative/absolute) in `is_file()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$le_map_to_search = $main;
$data_to_use_maps[] = array();
$data_to_use_maps = read_dir($le_map_to_search, 'dir');
$aantal_mappen = count($data_to_use_maps);
$counter_mappen = 1;
while($counter_mappen < $aantal_mappen){
   echo $data_to_use_maps[$counter_mappen];
   $counter_mappen++;
}

$data_to_use_files[] = array();
$data_to_use_files = read_dir($le_map_to_search, 'files');
$aantal_bestanden = count($data_to_use_files);
$counter_files = 1;
while($counter_files < $aantal_files){
   echo $data_to_use_files [$counter_files ];
   $counter_files ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the reference here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`$handle = opendir($directory);             //Open the directory

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))   {

$filepath = $directory.DS.$file;   //Get all files/directories in the directory

}`